# Cannot launch VS Code remote desktop as user, but can login as user via terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I've run into a problem where I can't launch a Remote Desktop Session in VS Code when I use my username, but I can with root. In a normal ssh session through zsh terminal, I can log into both root and username normally.

My ~/.ssh/config on my laptop looks like this

```
Host greenpatch.dev
  HostName greenpatch.dev
  User jake
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-awesome-key
```

When I try ssh-ing using remote desktop in VS code, it says it cannot connect. The output I see in the terminal is the following:

```
### shows the normal ubuntu success screen, ssh key worked and all, then
ready: 4e672f435229
Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021
4e672f435229: running
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: line 1: `]; then'
-sh: 4: function: not found
-sh: 69: [[: not found
-sh: 90: [[: not found
-sh: 149: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

My temporary work around is changing my config to login as root:

```
Host greenpatch.dev
  HostName greenpatch.dev
  User root
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-awesome-key
```

then I `su - jake`. The root works in VS Code remote desktop.

The strange thing is, I can `ssh jake@greenpatch.dev` just fine. It's only happening in the VS Code remote desktop.

- I've checked that my authorized keys in `/home/jake/.ssh/authorized_keys` are updated
- I've restarted my laptop, thinking there was a caching issue
- I stopped and restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

I found IT! My user, jake, was logging in via shell and not bash. I ssh-ed into via a terminal as `jake` the I ran the command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

That set my default shell as bash instead of sh. I launched the remote desktop session in VS Code and it worked perfectly. I guess VS Code doesn't switch to bash for you, so the error was happening because the VS Code extension was trying to run a bash script in sh.